# URL Routing in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, url-routing

Coming from other web frameworks, I'm used to being able to map parts of a URL to method parameters.  I know that web.xml provides a way to map an entire URL to a Servlet but is there  a way to get more features out of this, such as mapping pieces of the URL to method parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Spring (MVC) is overkill for this. If you don't need dependency injection, you'll be happy with [redirect filter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/).

Answer (score 4):

Actually, most MVC frameworks support RESTful actions (i.e. allow to map URLs on methods of actions): Spring MVC, [Stripes](http://ilkinbalkanay.blogspot.com/2008/02/restful-urls-with-stripes.html), Struts 2 with the [REST plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/rest-plugin.html).

If you're not using any of them, you could achieve this with URL rewriting. The [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) is pretty famous and allows to implements such things. From the documentation about [Method Invocation](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/3.2/guide.html#method):

> The standard servlet mapping that is
>   done via web.xml is rather limiting.
>   Only *.xxx or /xxxx/*, no abilty to
>   have any sort of smart matching. Using
>   UrlRewriteFilter any rule when matched
>   can be set to run method(s) on a
>   class.
>
> Invoke a servlet directly
>
> ```
> <rule>
> <from>^/products/purchase$</from>
> <run class="com.blah.web.MyServlet" method="doGet" />
> </rule>
> ```
>
> This will invoke
>   doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
>   HttpServletResponse response) when the
>   "from" is matched on a request.
>   (remeber this method needs to be
>   public!)
>
> Use it to delegate cleanly to your
>   methods
>
> ```
> <rule>
>     <from>^/pref-editor/addresses$</from>
>     <run class="com.blah.web.PrefsServlet" method="runAddresses" />
> </rule>
> <rule>
>     <from>^/pref-editor/phone-nums$</from>
>     <run class="com.blah.web.PrefsServlet" method="runPhoneNums" />
> </rule>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I have written a library called [jurlmap](http://jurlmap.codegremlins.com/) which among other things does what you are asking for.

Comment: Ah, your server is down. It is better to share projects on Github.

Comment: I have it on github: https://github.com/mtomis/jurlmap, but I am not sure how useful it still is.

Answer (score 1):

You can do such things with Spring web MVC.  Their controller API can map parts of the URL to specific calls on the back end.